# Reference books/material for axiomatic/rigorous treatment of pre-university topics

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request

Taking undergraduate analysis and algebra classes in University made me appreciate the axiomatic construction of the topic under study. I would like reference material/books to work through/read of important topics introduced prior to College for further appreciation. A proof/axiomatic driven approach for these topics would be great :

- Material for constructing Euclidean geometry in an axiomatic fashion. (The things I took for granted like areas, angles and identities about triangles, quadrilaterals, circles and parallel lines)
- Material for establishing the axiomatic correspondence between Euclidean geometry and algebra (coordinate geometry / geometric interpretation of vectors)
- Material developing trigonometry in a rigorous manner and deriving the identities and studying the properties of the trigonometric functions
- Material developing complex numbers in a comprehensive fashion and proofs of important results like De-Moivres theorem

Comment: as far as I know the unique axioms that you need are the axioms of ZFC to build almost any mathematical object. Euclidean geometry through axioms is how geometry first appeared in history, its a bit old-fashioned but you can read about it in any book dedicated to synthetic geometry, this will cover the first two points. The other points are covered in any introductory text to real and complex analysis, there (maybe) you can see the real numbers defined axiomatically, however this is not necessary after the construction of the reals by Dedekind.

Comment: continuation: also, in some introductory book of analysis, you can read about the Peano axioms to define the natural numbers, however as I said before you dont really need it after the development of ZFC. There you can find, with the search bar, many recommendations for the mentioned topics: real analysis, complex analysis and synthetic geometry.